# Data loads but won't save iPhone app

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I've been stuck on this for approximately two weeks. I hate posting things that have been asked a lot but I really have gone through them all.

I used Ray Wenderlich's tutorial for saving data in an iPhone app.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials

So that is the setup I have going on in my app. I'm saving very simple objects. My Card object consists of a name, type, and image. That's all. So the tutorial is quite close to mine. Which is making this more frustrating.

The thing is, I have some NSLog statements in there for loading. I have it displaying the folder it's using to load and what objects it does load. Right now it is displaying this.

```
Loading cards from /Users/zach/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3-64/Applications/E3DB01FD-A37E-4A69-840B-43830F2BDE2C/Library/Private Documents
2013-11-04 00:02:50.073 CardMinder[84170:a0b] ()
```

So it seems to be trying to load them, but there's nothing there to load. Here is my function to save data.

```
- (void)saveData {
    if (_data == nil) return;

    [self createDataPath];

    NSString *dataPath = [_docPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:kDataFile];
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];
    [archiver encodeObject:_data forKey:kDataKey];
    [archiver finishEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@",dataPath);
    NSLog(@"%@",data);

    [data writeToFile:dataPath atomically:YES];

}
```

Which is really just what's posted in that tutorial. I know if you feel generous enough to help me out i'll have to post some more code but I don't want to flood the post with useless stuff so just let me know and i'll get it out here.

I really appreciate anyone that can help, I have recently entered the desperation state and need help.

Thanks

UPDATE

```
    NSError *error;
    [data writeToFile:dataPath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
    NSLog(@"error: %@", error.localizedFailureReason);
```

These are the methods for the CardData class. I'm doing the name, type, and a bool here.

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:_name forKey:kNameKey];
    [aCoder encodeObject:_cardType forKey:kTypeKey];
    [aCoder encodeBool:_checkedOut forKey:kOutKey];

}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    NSString *name = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kNameKey];
    NSString *cardType = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:kTypeKey];
    BOOL checkedOut = [aDecoder decodeBoolForKey:kOutKey];
    return [self initWithName:name cardType:cardType _Bool:checkedOut];
}
```

UPDATE 2

I just put some more NSLog statements in and I found out that when I press the "Save card" button in my app, it doesn't seem to execute the saveData function at all. I have log statements galore in that saveData function and when I click the saveCard button it doesn't show any of those logs. Why would that be happening?

This is my saveButton code.

```
- (IBAction)saveNewCard:(id)sender
{
    NSString *cardName = self.nameField.text;

    _cardDoc.data.name = cardName;


    CardDoc *newCard = [[CardDoc alloc] initWithName:cardName cardType:cardTypeString _Bool:NO image:chosenIcon];

    [_cardDoc saveData];
    NSLog(@"Card save button pressed!");

    CardViewController *cardViewController = (CardViewController *)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:self.navigationController.viewControllers.count-2];

    [cardViewController.cards addObject:newCard];
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];


}
```

Comment: You should use `writeToFile:options:error:` instead of `writeToFile:atomically:`; that will give you an error message that should prove helpful. (The equivalent to `atomically:YES` is the option constant `NSDataWritingAtomic`.)

Comment: I added the lines I posted in the update on my post, that's correct right? If so, it's not giving me an error. Which makes me think it's not this function. Which is not good lol

Comment: The usual way to check the error would be `if (![data writeToFile:...]) {`, then log inside the block. My guess if you're seeing no error there is that `data` is `nil`. In Objective-C, messaging `nil` is valid.

Comment: Likely reason for saveNewCard not firing: It's not connected to the button in your storyboard.

Comment: saveNewCard is firing. I have it connected, I just did it through the dragging in the storyboard. The "Card save button pressed!" log shows up. It's saveData that isn't firing cause i'm not getting any of those logs

Comment: If `saveData` isn't firing, it's because `_cardDoc` is nil.

Comment: Holy crap, you just made my day. _cardDoc wasn't nil, but I wasn't wanting to save _cardDoc, I was wanting to save the CardDoc item newCard that I created. I just had the wrong variable.

Comment: I think I have a problem loading them now, but it is indeed saving them. Thank you so much!

Comment: If you want to post something as an answer, i'll click the checkmark for you

Comment: I tried to write something that would be useful for the future, and not go too deep for you at your current level. Good luck. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `writeToFile:options:error:` instead of `writeToFile:atomically:`; that will give you an error message that should prove helpful. (The equivalent to `atomically:YES` is the option constant `NSDataWritingAtomic`.) Make sure you're getting back a return value of `YES`; if not, the error should be set.

If you're getting a value of `NO` but the error is not set, it means you're messaging `nil`. A quirk of Objective-C is that messaging `nil` is completely valid. If the method is defined to return something, you'll even get a result: `0` or equivalent (`NO`, `nil`, etc.)

In this case, you're messaging `_cardDoc`. There's no return result to detect. This is a bit harder to defensively code around, but `[_cardDoc saveData]` is actually `[nil saveData]`. The debugger will just breeze past the line.

Generally, if something absolutely should not be `nil`, you can use `NSAssert`:

```
NSAssert(_cardData, @"_cardData should not be nil");
[_cardData saveData];
```

But use this sparingly; you'll probably come to usually appreciate this behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for that NSAssert bit. Really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

A few things.

Post the results of your log statements so we know what you are seeing.

In order for your approach to work, your _data object needs to conform to the NSCoding protocol. That means you need to add the protocol declaration to your interface, and implement the methods encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder.

In those methods you need to save all the state data for your object / load the state back into your object.

Those methods are the most likely source of problems with your code. Post those methods if you need help with them, and walk though them in the debugger.

You might also look at the NSKeyedArchvier class method archivedDataWithRootObject. That method takes an object and encodes it into an NSData object in one step. The method archiveRootObject:toFile: take it a step further, and writes the data directly to a file for you.

NSKeyedUnarchiver has the corresponding methods unarchiveObjectWithData and unarchiveObjectWithFile to recreate your object from data/a file.

Comment: Alright, here we go. I do have my _data object conforming to the NSCoding protocol, I do know that. And I have the encodeWithCoder and initWithCoder methods implemented. I'll post those, I thought those were fairly straightforward. I've been reading on the NSKeyedArchiver but i'm not sure i'm using it correctly. I think i'm overcomplicating it. I feel like there are easier ways than the tutorial i used but i've got it all set up so i'd like to just make it work.